# ¿Qué hacer con una pregunta marcada como duplicada, pero que realmente no lo es?

Tags: discusión, duplicados

La pregunta [Cannot read property 'length' of undefined en javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/316753/cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined-en-javascript/) fue marcada como duplicada, indicando que la otra pregunta era: [¿Qué significa el error “Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set/read property 'XXX' of undefined/null” y cómo solucionarlo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169194/qu%c3%a9-significa-el-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-read-property-xxx-of-u).

Creo que, si bien el mensaje de error es el mismo, la pregunta original en el contexto del OP tiene un origen diferente.

Si analiza uno la pregunta del OP, se da cuenta que el error lo genera internamente la el componente utilizado (`dojo`en este caso).

Al ser un componente "externo", es dificil que el OP pueda guiarse con una pregunta más orientada al lenguaje que al componente que esté utilizando y quizas las respuestas de la pregunta asociada en el duplicado no le sean de mucha ayuda.

Si bien, no se si se pueda quitar la "marca de duplicado", escribo en el meta para preguntar si existe en SoEs algún mecanismo para solicitar o proponer que se remueva esta "marca".

Comment: Si se puede quitar. Todo es reversible. Lo que veo, es que mas alla de tu respuesta, en ningun lado esta aclarado que el error es generado por un componente externo a JS puro.. eso hubiera estado bueno aclararlo en la pregunta y en la respuesta tambien.. porque todos nos quedamos con el comentario de que esa propiedad no estaba en ningun lado..

Comment: Me parece que está impícito en la respuesta. Sin embargo, como lo comenté en Meta, mi pregunta está orientada a "¿Cuál es el procedimiento para solicitar que se revise la marca de 'duplicada' de una pregunta?".

Comment: Este es el procedimiento adecuado ;)

Comment: Siendo así, marcaré la respuesta de @pablo-lozano como respuesta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Creo que tienes razón y he retirado mi voto de cierre. Me precipité al dar mi voto y debí tener más cuidado, sabiendo que mi voto cerraba.

Gracias por el aviso!

### Actualización:

No he respondido para el caso general, así que propongo los siguientes pasos:

- Poner un comentario en la pregunta indicando la duda/petición
- Crear una petición en Meta, como has hecho en este caso.
- Intentar contactar con el usuario que cerró la pregunta o con un moderador en el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol).