# ¿Por qué se marcó una pregunta de AngularJS como duplicada de una de Angular?

Tags: discusión, pregunta-específica, duplicados

Ayer reporté una pregunta sobre AngularJS como no duplicada porque dicha duplicidad refiere a una pregunta similar pero referente a Angular 8.

La pregunta es [¿Formatear fecha en Angular?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/361477/83).

Este reporte no ha sido aceptado. Tampoco se explica el motivo.

El problema es que angular8 y angulasJS son tecnologías diferentes. Además, ANGULAR8 no contiene la librería `$filter` que se utiliza en la solución.

Siendo además aceptada dicha la solución de AngularJS por **el usuario original que indica además QUE LA PREGUNTA QUE SE DICE COMO DUPLICADA NO LE DA LA SOLUCIÓN**:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pregunta es esta. Se debe modificar el título porque es AngularJS y no Angular 8.

Sí que se aceptó en cambio un edit en el que yo puse las etiquetas AngularJS pero no aparece el título modificado.

¿Qué ocurre aquí?

La documentación de la propia ANGULAR donde se indica dicha diferencia entre lenguajes/versiones 
https://angular.io/guide/ajs-quick-reference

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Más documentación al respecto:

https://blog.imaginea.com/pipe-vs-filter-in-angular-js/
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Se rechazó una sugerencia de edición a tu cambio de título, pero acabo de hacer una revisión más exhaustiva de la pregunta. Dicho lo cual, es bueno notar que la sugerencia de duplicado se la diste tú inicialmente y el usuario (como indica gbianchi) se debió liar y la dio por válida. Efectivamente hay un jaleo con las etiquetas de Angular y AngularJS y habría que pedir a los moderadores que lo revisen. Dicho lo cual, tanta negrita y mayúscula resultan algo estruendosos, por lo que los he reducido.

Answer (score 1):

A ver.. meta no es para solucionar errores tecnicos en respuestas o preguntas, para eso estan las respuestas mismas, los comentarios o lo que sea necesario para explicarlo.

La pregunta fue cerrada por duplicado por comunidad (se puede ver en el timeline [aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/361477/timeline))

Eso quiere decir, que quien cerro la pregunta como duplicada fue el mismo usuario. Cuando al usuario se le dice que hay una pregunta que posiblemente resuelva su duda (o sea, que su pregunta es un duplicado) se le da la opción de aceptar que esa pregunta contesta su duda.

Supongo que al ser un usuario novato, no supo como usar el sitio y acepto la duplicidad, aunque no contestaba su pregunta particular.

Podemos reabrirla a pedido del usuario, si este cometio un error.

Si la pregunta no es sobre angular, entonces hay que quitar todas las etiquetas, para que quede claro que la pregunta no es sobre eso. En este momento, la pregunta tiene varias etiquetas angular.

Si hay que modificar un enunciado porque esta erroneo, eso es tarea de quien pregunto, o en tu caso, se pone una respuesta a la pregunta, se indican los errores y se indica la solución. Los moderadores diamantados del sitio no esta para ocuparse de errores tecnicos, para eso esta la comunidad.

Cualquier otra duda, puedes indicarle al usuario que lea esta publicación, y que indique si quiere que su pregunta sea reabierta, una vez que modifiquen los erroes de forma en la pregunta y las etiquetas.

Comment: Disculpa pero un usuario con mucha puntuación sugiere que lo comente en META, por eso lo he hecho, igual que también he aclarado en el chat. 
No debnería ser un tema a discutir. Está más que claro que No se trata de un duplicado

https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4483/qu%c3%a9-hacer-con-una-pregunta-marcada-como-duplicada-pero-que-realmente-no-lo-es/4484#4484
-     Poner un comentario en la pregunta indicando la duda/petición
-    Crear una petición en Meta, como has hecho en este caso.
-   Intentar contactar con el usuario que cerró la pregunta o con un moderador en el chat.

Comment: Y ya solicité modificaciones sobre el enunuciado PERO NO APARECEN.. qué más hace falta??

Comment: Aquí tienes mi EDIT: https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/215633

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz tu edicion esta en la cola de edicion.. sin embargo, no arregla los problemas de la pregunta, como que no tiene nada que ver con angular (dicho por vos mismo en la respuesta y un comentario). Esto no es una pelea, tratemos de ordenar las cosas. Entiendo tu punto de vista y tenes razon. Voy a rechazar la edicion, asi podes editarla como corresponde. En cuanto a la duplicidad, una vez modificada, podemos levantar eso tambien. Pero entende que salvo levantar la duplicidad, el resto de los temas no corresponden a moderadores diamantados. No se con quien hablaste.

Comment: Hay otra pregunta abierta en relación a las etiquetas de Angular vs AngularJS. Cuál es la política a utilizar?https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2762/16285

Comment: No he hablado con nadie... simplemente alguien la contó como duplicada, puse un reporte al respecto, y ese reporte se ha rechazado sin más motivo  :( entiendo que los moderadores pueden tener dudas, pero esta duda ya corre por stackoverflow hace tiempo. No sólo aquí.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con lo que comenta gbianchi. Eso sí, el AP aquí también menciona un reporte que fue rechazado.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' dos reportes se rechazaron.. uno lo soluciono solo comunidad, el otro lo rechaze yo, porque hablaba de que el titulo esta mal y de que las etiquetas no correspondian, cosa sobre la cual no me puedo hacer cargo (o no tengo porque) y de las cuales se podia hacer cargo quien lo reporto.. no era un reporte que tuvieramos que manejar nosotros...

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Creo que Alejandro mezcla la moderacion del sitio con una curacion de las preguntas. Tal vez nos pueda dejar eso en claro.

Comment: @gbianchi gracias! Absolutamente de acuerdo en el rechazo al reporte ("no es algo que dependa de los moderadores sino que la comunidad puede gestionarlo", etc). Yo miraba la línea de tiempo de la pregunta (https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/361477/timeline) y no veía ninguna mención a voto de reapertura